# How can I open (launch) files using the terminal?

Tags: command-line

**Objective:** *Open a text file and other types using the terminal.*

Let's suppose I have a file named `myFile.txt` and I want to launch this file (*open it, not sure how I'm supposed to say it*), how can I do this?

As I searched all I could find was articles about create and edit files or display the content in the terminal.

Some of the failed attempts:

> `./myFile.txt`
>
> `/myFile.txt`
>
> `cd myFile.txt`
>
> `cd ./myFile.txt`
>
> `cd /myFile.txt`
>
> `eog myFile.txt`

And, yes, I used the commands in the folder containing the file in question.

Comment: Hm, it's not immediately obvious to me what you want to do with the file. If you don't want to *view* or *edit* it, what exactly do you want to do with it? I'm only asking because your answer will help people recommend a particular program to you that will do what you want. (Typically, when one asks how to launch or open a file, they mean something like view or edit the contents.)

Comment: Alternatively, if the file is a *program* that you are trying to run or execute, you may be doing it correctly with `./myFile.txt`, but you only need to set the file to be executable: `chmod +x myFile.txt`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you create `myfile.txt` in the first place or did something else create it? If you created it what program did you use to create it? This question might be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5):

`xdg-open` will try to guess your desktop environment and the file's mime type and try to open it in the appropriate application:

```
xdg-open myFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

### Select the tool manually

Typically, when using the terminal window and command lines, you are expected to know which tool you want to use. I know that this can be difficult in the beginning, but there are several things you might want to do.

If you use a graphical file manager, there is

- a main tool (for the main task), that you start by left-double-clicking on the file's icon.
- and often a few other tools (for other tasks), that you can select after right-clicking on the file's icon.

The main tasks for a text file might be editing and viewing.

- In standard Ubuntu desktop there is `gedit` for these tasks.
- If you want only viewing in text mode, you can use `less`
- If you want to edit in text mode, you can use `nano`

So I suggest that you try

```
gedit file.txt
less file.txt
nano file.txt
```

You mentioned some alternatives that do not work (because ...)

> ```
> ./myFile.txt
> ```

This is typically used to run an executable file

> ```
> /myFile.txt
> ```

This points to a file in the root directory **/**

> ```
> cd myFile.txt
> cd ./myFile.txt
> cd /myFile.txt
> ```

This changes the terminal window to the specified directory (`cd` 'change directory' makes the terminal window look at the specified directory. You should specify a directory (not a file) after the `cd` command.)

> ```
> eog myFile.txt
> ```

`eog` "Eye of Gnome" is a viewer for picture files.

### `xdg-open`

Until you know which tool to use, you can try with `xdg-open`. It will select a tool for you depending of the kind of file you are using. I would expect that it will select `gedit` for text files and `eog` for picture files (in standard Ubuntu desktop).

```
xdg-open file.txt
```